# Updated Information In JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have a JFrame "GameWindow" and a class named "Combat".

I am trying to update various components in GameWindow (JLabels, JProgressBars, etc.) from variables in the Combat class. However, the details never seem to update. Consider the following:

```
public class Combat {
public static String attackName1;
public static String pUnitName;

public static void setPlayerUnit(GameUnit u) {

    attackName1 = u.getAttackName1();
    pUnitName = u.getName().toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

and:

```
 public GameWindow() {

    initialize();
    gameFrame.setVisible(true);
}

 private void initialize() {        
    gameFrame = new JFrame();
    gameFrame.setResizable(false);
    gameFrame.setTitle("GameWindow");
    gameFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 480);
    gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

 JButton pAttack1 = new JButton(Combat.attackName1);  //<--------NOT BEING CHANGED
    sl_gamePanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pAttack1, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, gameTextPanel);
    sl_gamePanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pAttack1, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, textAttackSeparator);
    sl_gamePanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pAttack1, 34, SpringLayout.NORTH, gameTextPanel);
    sl_gamePanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pAttack1, 157, SpringLayout.EAST, textAttackSeparator);
    gamePanel.add(pAttack1);

 JLabel pMobName = new JLabel(Combat.pUnitName); //<--------NOT BEING CHANGED
    sl_pPanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pMobName, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, pPanel);
    sl_pPanel.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pMobName, 129, SpringLayout.WEST, pPanel);
    pPanel.add(pMobName);
```

Why are is the text for the buttons/JLabels not being updated? Do I need to change using "Combat.variable" to "Combat.getVariable()"? Is this even possible, and if so, how can I make it work?

Comment: *What* is not working? I see no code in your MouseListener at all, so that certainly won't do anything. Incidentally, don't use a MouseListener with a JButton. Use an ActionListener as the tutorials that I'm sure you read will tell you. If you still need help, consider creating and posting a very small simple program that compiles, runs, shows us your problem and only does this and no more, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: "I am trying to update various components in GameWindow (JLabels, JProgressBars, etc.) from variables in the Combat class. Why does this not work?"

Comment: Where in your code above are you showing us your attempt to do this? What in your code is not working? Again, get rid of the MouseListener and use an ActionListener for a JButton.

Comment: *"the entire JFrame code is extremely long."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state:

> JButton pAttack1 = new JButton(Combat.attackName1); As stated, the text on the JButton is not updated when changing the variable in the combat class.

You're confusing a reference variable with the object it represents and need to understand that they are different. While initially Combat.attackName1 and the JButton's name refer to the same String object, Strings are immutable. When you change the String object that the variable is referring to this will have no effect on the String displayed by the JButton. Solution: call the JButton's `setText(...)` method if you want to change its displayed text.